# Issues in using Selenium with python script on Mac (webdriver: firefox driver / geckodriver)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to use selenium with a Python script on my mac that requires firefox (& I've cloned geckodriver from github) but for some reason, there seems to be some type of issue with the webdriver (I know it needs firefoxdriver & firebug, I got geckodriver). I'm really like a noob (I'm a CS student & sort of a beginner trying to learn). I feel like maybe my issue has to do with my Firefox profile not being in the Path but i really don't know. This is the error I'm getting:

```
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
self.binary, timeout)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
 % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile.  Profile Dir:    /var/folders/jr/61813w490n14yrp433c8d9zr0000gn/T/tmpIeQVyC If you  specified a    log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I found another solution to a similar problem to mine [Firefox driver can't start for Selenium 3.0.1 with FF49 and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455598/firefox-driver-cant-start-for-selenium-3-0-1-with-ff49-and-python)
but in python I get:

> > > from selenium import webdriver
> > >       browser = webdriver.Firefox()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 103, in **init**
> > >           self.binary, timeout)
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in **init**
> > >           self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
> > >           self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
> > >           % (self.profile.path))
> > >       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/jr/61813w490n14yrp433c8d9zr0000gn/T/tmp6f_7bG If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

So, if anyone might have any idea what's wrong w/my selenium & webdriver- when I installed Selenium I got this error:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Users/tamarafrankel/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
  import packaging.version
  ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

Any help would really be appreciated- I've scoured the internet for days trying to find a solution & trying various things.

Also, I found this question which was similar: [Selenium: FirefoxProfile exception Can't load the profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682009/selenium-firefoxprofile-exception-cant-load-the-profile?rq=1) but I'm running the script with sudo and I am using the command pip install -U selenium (both of which they say are fixes to this problem)

Comment: Can you explain how you installed your GeckoDriver? Did you use one of the preconfigured release downloads or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: yes- I downloaded it &  `brew install geckodriver`

Comment: @A.Kootstra `brew install geckodriver`

Comment: In your error message is highlights a path: "Profile Dir:    /var/folders/jr/61813w490n14yrp433c8d9zr0000gn/T/tmpIeQVyC". Is it possible that this path is not created or accessible to the user running the script? Have you found the log file referred: "If you  specified a    log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details." In case you haven't specified, have a look at the github page: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. Separately, have you tried starting the webdriver on its own?